# Ansible http get request does not work but manual curl get works

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault, ansible-vault

I have the following task in my ansible playbook:

```
- name: Test on localhost
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Get vault vaules
      uri:
        url: "{{vault_address_personal}}/v1/{{vault_path_personal}}/pg"
        method: GET
        validate_certs: no
        headers:
          X-Vault-Token: "36f8a4d9-64fd-a2ec-b45a-fd041f7e28df"
      register: pg_value
```

This task fails with:

```
TASK [Get vault vaules] *******************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"cache_control": "no-store", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "{\"errors\":[\"permission denied\"]}\n", "content_length": "33", "content_type": "application/json", "date": "Wed, 27 Mar 2019 15:44:29 GMT", "failed": true, "json": {"errors": ["permission denied"]}, "msg": "Status code was not [200]: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden", "redirected": false, "status": 403, "url": "https://vserv-us.sos.ibm.com:8200/v1/generic/user/xyz/pg"}
```

However when I curl I get proper vaules:

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: 36f8a4d9-64fd-a2ec-b45a-fd041f7e28df" https://vserv-us.sos.ibm.com:8200/v1/generic/user/xyz/pg --insecure
{"request_id":"662fb6f5-5271-0551-de6b-cdf7d873f410","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":2764800,"data":{"password":"p0wn-me"},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null}
```

Looks like ansible not considering the header. Anything missing here?

I also tried:

```
"X-Vault-Token": "36f8a4d9-64fd-a2ec-b45a-fd041f7e28df"
```

I went through some issues where it says the headers might be capitalized automatically. so also tried

```
"X-VAULT-TOKEN": "36f8a4d9-64fd-a2ec-b45a-fd041f7e28df"
```

Works well with curl. Also tried postman and noticed there is a header for Authorization automatically added in postman with value `Basic Og==` So tried adding that additional header. But nothing worked.

Also tried hashi_vault but got same error:

```
- name: Return all secrets from a path
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Return all secrets from a path
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=generic/user/xyz/pg token=36f8a4d9-64fd-a2ec-b45a-fd041f7e28df url=https://vserv-us.sos.ibm.com:8200 validate_certs=False')}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

After lot of debugging I figured out there was some issue with the url formation. Looking the error its very tempting to assume there is something wrong with the headers. I wish there was some more useful error like `404` or `400` when the url itself is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Kibana API (7.17.14).

That works:

```
curl -sku elastic:password POST "http://kibana.local:5601/api/index_patterns/index_pattern" -H 'kbn-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "override": true, "refresh_fields": true, "index_pattern": { "title": "*" }}'
```

But this one isn't:

```
- name: Create data view in Kibana
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "http://{{ inventory_hostname }}:5601/api/index_patterns/index_pattern"
    method: POST
    user: elastic
    password: "{{ elastic_user_password }}"
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: false
    headers:
      kbn-xsrf: "true"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    body:
      override: true
      refresh_fields: true
      index_pattern:
        title: "*"
    status_code: 200
```

Get error:

```
"msg": "Status code was 401 and not [200]: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized", "redirected": false, "referrer_policy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade", "status": 401, "url": "http://kibana.local:5601/api/index_patterns/index_pattern", "x_content_type_options": "nosniff"
```

just adding `force_basic_auth: true` parameter to uri module resolve the problem:

```
- name: Create data view in Kibana
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "http://{{ inventory_hostname }}:5601/api/index_patterns/index_pattern"
    method: POST
    user: elastic
    password: "{{ elastic_user_password }}"
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: false
    force_basic_auth: true
    headers:
      kbn-xsrf: "true"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    body:
      override: true
      refresh_fields: true
      index_pattern:
        title: "*"
    status_code: 200
```